# How to draw more than one shape on canvas while visualizing rubber band?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using canvas and js to make a painting tool with a rubber band. Currently it draws ellipses, but each time I start to drag for a new shape - the previous one erases due to specifics of rubberBand function, cause it clears the canvas every time. Is there any way to fix that?

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ThePanda/bspf5v40/

**HTML (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:4px; left:4px;"><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
    <script>
      canvasEngine();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS (style.css):**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

**JavaScript (index.js):**

```
function canvasEngine() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 12;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 12;

  //letiables
  let canvasStartX = 4;
  let canvasStartY = 4;
  let lastMouseY, lastMouseX;
  let mouseX, mouseY;
  let width, height;

  let mousedown = false;

  //Mousedown
  function startPosition(e) {
    lastMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasStartX);
    lastMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasStartY);
    mousedown = true;
  };

  //Mousemove
  function rubberBand(e) {
    if (!mousedown) return;

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasStartX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasStartY);

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    width = mouseX-lastMouseX;
    height = mouseY-lastMouseY;
    ctx.rect(lastMouseX,lastMouseY,width,height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  //Mouseup
  function finishedPosition(e) {
    mousedown = false;

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasStartX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasStartY);

    width = mouseX - lastMouseX;
    height = mouseY - lastMouseY;

    const rw = Math.abs(width/2);
    const rh = Math.abs(height/2);

    let centerX = mouseX - width/2;
    let centerY = mouseY - height/2;

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.ellipse(centerX,centerY,rw,rh,0,0,2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", rubberBand);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is mostly correct for what you are trying to achieve.

The main problem is that you call `ctx.clearRect` each time you draw something new. This way the whole canvas is cleared and your old ellipses are gone.

I've tried to make minimal changes to your code to fix this:

```js
function canvasEngine() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 12;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 12;
  
  //letiables
  let canvasStartX = 4;
  let canvasStartY = 4;
  let lastMouseY, lastMouseX;
  let mouseX, mouseY;
  let width, height;
  
  let mousedown = false;
  
  let ellipses = [];

 function drawEllipse(ellipse) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.ellipse(
     ellipse.centerX,
      ellipse.centerY,
      ellipse.rw,
      ellipse.rh,
      0,
      0,
      2 * Math.PI
    );
    ctx.stroke();
  }

 function drawEllipses() {
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
   
   ellipses.forEach(drawEllipse)
  }

  //Mousedown
  function startPosition(e) {
    lastMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasStartX);
    lastMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasStartY);
    mousedown = true;
  };
  
  //Mousemove
  function rubberBand(e) {
    if (!mousedown) return;

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasStartX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasStartY);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    drawEllipses();

    ctx.beginPath();
    width = mouseX-lastMouseX;
    height = mouseY-lastMouseY;
    ctx.rect(lastMouseX,lastMouseY,width,height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  //Mouseup
  function finishedPosition(e) {
    mousedown = false;

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasStartX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasStartY);

    width = mouseX - lastMouseX;
    height = mouseY - lastMouseY;
    
    const rw = Math.abs(width/2);
    const rh = Math.abs(height/2);
    
    let centerX = mouseX - width/2;
    let centerY = mouseY - height/2;
    
    // Add the ellipse to the list of ellipses
    ellipses.push({ centerX, centerY, rw, rh })

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    drawEllipses();
  };
  
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", rubberBand);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
};

canvasEngine();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:4px; left:4px;"><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: One more thing: this program will also have at least several different shapes based on classes + the color will change by select.
So here:
`function drawElipses() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    elipses.forEach(drawEllipse)
  };`

I can't just draw back ellipses again. I will need to draw back all previous shapes with their parameters. Any thoughts how to implement this and make this code more universal?

Comment: You could of course change the array `ellipses` into an array `shapes` in which each element contains a `shape` field that can be `"ellipse"` and a `color` field that might be `"black"`. Based on this fields you can then call a different draw function. Hope this helps :)